# Returning all matching rows to a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets that I am comparing and I'm trying to return all matching rows from the first worksheet into a listbox. The two worksheets compare based on the values in column L on both sheets.  So far I can only get it to return the first matching row. Any suggestions?

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 3 To lastRowData
        If wsInv.Cells(i, "L").Value = wsData.Cells(j, "L").Value Then
            matchingRows.Add wsInv.Rows(i).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For Each row In matchingRows
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List = row
Next row
```

Comment: What is `matchingRows`? A collection? Is it declare somewhere else than the code you show?

Comment: *So far I can only get it to return the first matching row.* Looks likeyour first loop is referenced to first worksheet and then because you do  `matchingRows.Add wsInv.Rows(i).Value` **in the second loop** then your first match is returned once for each match found. Not tested but try adding `Exit For` right after `matchingRows.Add wsInv.Rows(i).Value` so once a match is found, exit second loop, return to first loop and keep searching

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, matchingRows is a new Collection declared in the beginning of my code, too large to post all of it.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Tried that, still only returns one row. I Actually think that the row thats being returned is overwritten each time. It appears that the last row is the one being returned instead of the first as i originally thought.

Comment: If you do  not show relevant parts of your code, it is difficult to be helped, I am afraid... I cannot believe that you really need to place in the list box the **whole row**. Please, try the code I pasted. But **as it is**, only using the correct used objects name. Try implementing it in your 'large' code only after seeing it working as you need. I have bad experiences, from this point of view...

Comment: What is the value of `lastRow`? Looks like your first loop is being executed only once

Comment: Are you aware that a row has 16384 cells and on each match, you are writing a 2D one-based single-row array (`wsInv.Rows(i).Value`) of so many values (columns) to the collection? How do you think the poor list box could process so many columns? Maybe you want to return only the values from a few specific columns. Please clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I was not aware of that info. Thank you. I only wanted to return the whole row containg values, which is the first 13 columns.

Comment: That's another story. See FaneDuru's code. He's got that covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show only a slice of a code, without variables declarations, so it is difficult to be helped...

Please, try the next adapted code, and take care to use **your real names (sheets, list box)**:

```
Sub AddInListBox()
  Dim wsInv As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, LastrowData As Long, wsData As Worksheet, arr, k As Long
  Dim ListBox1 As MSForms.listbox, i As Long, j As Long, c as Long, arrRow
  
  Set wsInv = Worksheets("your INV sheet")    'use here the real shet
  Set wsData = Worksheets("your Data Sheet")  'use here the correct one
  lastRow = wsInv.Range("L" & wsInv.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  LastrowData = wsData.Range("L" & wsData.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  Set ListBox1 = wsInv.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object 'use here the correct sheet and list box name
  ReDim arr(1 To lastRow, 1 To wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count)
  For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 3 To LastrowData
        If wsInv.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If wsInv.cells(i, "L").value = wsData.cells(j, "O").value Then
                k = k + 1
                arrRow = Intersect(wsInv.rows(i), wsInv.UsedRange).value
                For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                    arr(k, c) = arrRow(1, c)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To k)
arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

ListBox1.ColumnCount = wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count 'to see all columns...
ListBox1.List = arr
End Sub
```

The code is, of course, not tested but it should work if you use the real objects.

And I don't think that you really want placing **all rows** in the list box...

**Edited**:

```
Sub AddInListBoxVissibleRows()
  Dim wsInv As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, LastrowData As Long, wsData As Worksheet, arr, k As Long
  Dim ListBox1 As MSForms.listbox, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long, arrRow, rngVis As Range, iRow
  
  Set wsInv = Worksheets("your INV sheet")    'use here the real shet
  Set wsData = Worksheets("your Data Sheet")  'use here the correct one
  lastRow = wsInv.Range("L" & wsInv.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  LastrowData = wsData.Range("L" & wsData.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  Set ListBox1 = wsInv.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object 'use here the correct sheet and list box name
  ReDim arr(1 To lastRow, 1 To wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count)
  Set rngVis = wsInv.UsedRange.Resize(wsInv.UsedRange.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  For Each iRow In rngVis.rows
    For j = 2 To LastrowData
        If iRow.Columns("L").value = wsData.cells(j, "O").value Then
            k = k + 1
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                arr(k, c) = iRow.cells(1, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next j
Next iRow

arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To k)
arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

ListBox1.ColumnCount = wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count
ListBox1.List = arr
End Sub
```

It is more compact and a little faster...

**Second Edit**:

Please, try using this version which creates slices of necessary rows. Able to also deal with the single returned row:

```
Sub AddInListBoxVissibleRowsSlice()
  Dim wsInv As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, LastrowData As Long, wsData As Worksheet, arr, k As Long
  Dim ListBox1 As MSForms.listbox, i As Long, j As Long, c As Long, arrRow, rngVis As Range, iRow, NoRows As Long
  
  Set wsInv = ActiveSheet ' Worksheets("your INV sheet")    'use here the real shet
  Set wsData = ActiveSheet ' Worksheets("your Data Sheet")  'use here the correct one
  lastRow = wsInv.Range("L" & wsInv.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  LastrowData = wsData.Range("L" & wsData.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  NoRows = lastRow: If LastrowData > NoRows Then NoRows = LastrowData 'the larger number of rows
  
  Set ListBox1 = wsInv.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object 'use here the correct sheet and list box name
  
  ReDim arr(1 To NoRows, 1 To wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count)
  On Error Resume Next
   Set rngVis = wsInv.UsedRange.Resize(wsInv.UsedRange.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngVis Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No any visible row could be found...", vbInformation, "Stop code": Exit Sub
  
  For Each iRow In rngVis.rows
   If iRow.Columns("L").value = wsData.cells(LastrowData, "L").value Then
        k = k + 1
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(k, c) = iRow.cells(1, c)
        Next c
    End If
  Next iRow

  Dim cols As String
  cols = "A:" & Split(cells(1, rngVis.Columns.count).address, "$")(1) 'extract the columns letter to be evaluated

  If k = 1 Then
    Dim arr1
    arr = Application.Index(arr, k, 0)   'place the first row of the array in a 1D array
    ReDim arr1(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr)) 'Redim the 2D array to place it in the lis box horizontally
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr): arr1(1, i) = arr(i): Next i 'load the 2D array
    arr = arr1 'use the same array (arr) to load the list box
  Else
    arr = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & k & ")"), Evaluate("COLUMN(" & cols & ")"))
  End If

  With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = wsInv.UsedRange.Columns.count
    .List = arr
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what i was looking for. One minor thing though, the data in wsInv is filtered, I only want to add the rows of visible cells. Can we adjust to account for this?

Comment: @jjansen315 I was answering a previous comment which has been deleted in the meantime...  The code can be adjusted in many ways, but I would like to tell you that this was good to be clearly explained in your question. Besides, the context missing... So, only the first sheet is filtered. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Apologies. I should have provided more information from the beginning. Yes, only the first sheet is filtered. And it is filtered by column A if that matters. I'd only like to return visible rows into the listbox.

Comment: @jjansen315 OK. Adapted. Now the code previously check if the row is hidden. A second approach could be to firstly set the discontinuous range of visible cells, but I would need to adapt the code a little more... Iteration row by row couldn't work in the same way.

Comment: I will also edit and supply the version using the discontinuous range...

Comment: @jjansen315 Adapted. Please, test it and try understanding the difference. If the range to be placed in the list box is huge, `Transpose` function has some limitations. But I can supply a custom similar function able to do what the standard method does, with comparable speed, without the mentioned limitations. Also, `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` needs to have a kind of error handling. If no any visible cell in the range, it will raise an error. But I suppose that in the context you explained this cannot be happening. It is easy to be done, anyhow...

Comment: Thank you. I'm running it and it appears to be working. One thing though, it appears to hold the data everytime i run it. For example, the first time i run it, i get 2 rows added, which is expected, then the next time i run it, there are 4 rows, then 6, etc. Anyway to clear the data each time it runs?

Comment: @jjansen315 Do you use it as it is? It should load the array and delete existing. If you use the array to load the list box item by item (as I am afraid you do, and I do not understand why...), you firstly should use `ListBox1.clear`...

Comment: Yes i am using your code as is.

Comment: @jjansen315 Then, I cannot understand what's happening if I cannot see your environment. Anyhow, using `ListBox1.clear` before dropping the array content will always update only with the new array...

Comment: I see whats happening. It's matching all rows from column L in wsData sheet. My fault again for not being clear. i only want it to match the Last row of this sheet. So its adding more to my list box when i add more things to wsData sheet.

Comment: Last row of **which sheet**?

Comment: the Data sheet.

Comment: Also, if there is only one match found, it transposes the columns into individual rows in the listbox. If more than one match is found then it works fine.

Comment: I am driving now...

Comment: @jjansen315 Please, try the third version (after **Second Edit**). It is able to deal with what is to be done without so many transposing operations. It also solves the case of only one returned row. Now, what do you mean by "**I only want it to match the Last row of this sheet"**? Don't you want iteration between all rows in the second sheet? Do you want comparing each visible row of the first filtered range (column L) **with only one row of the second one** (column L)? With its **last one**? If so, I will adapt the last version...

Comment: The macro will be run many times, so i only want to compare each visible row in the first filtered range with the last row of the second sheet, wsData. Thank you.

Comment: @jjansen315 OK. Last edit... Please, test the adapted code. I am leaving home...